# what is the equivalent of https://graph.facebook.com/{user_id}?metadata=1&access_token={access_token} with a long lived access token?

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

The facebook api  below works fine but the user access token doesn't last.  Trying to find the alternative using the long lived access token.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{user_id}?metadata=1&access_token={access_token}
```

Should be simple enough but could not find it in the documenttion.

Looking for the equivalent URI that use the long lived access token.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the long lived token works the same in the same place as the short-lived token.  I guess I was just over thinking